# Abstracting from a closed interval to a closed and bounded set while proving the Heine-Borel Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm working on the following problem:

Consider the special case of the Heine-Borel Theorem where the set in question is a closed interval. Let {O λ : λ ∈ Λ} be an open cover for [a,b] and define S to be the set of all x ∈ [a,b] such that [a,x] has a finite subcover from {O_λ : λ ∈ Λ}.
(a) Argue that S is nonempty and bounded, and thus s = sup S exists.
(b) Now show s = b, which implies [a, b] has a finite subcover.
(c) Finally, prove the theorem for an arbitrary closed and bounded set K.

I successfully showed part a by demonstrating that the point a must be in S by the fact that the open cover must contain a set of the form (a-ε,a+δ) in order to cover a, and that S is bounded by [a,b] from which it is chosen.

I proceeded by contradiction for b, claiming that sup(S) = x, x ∈ [a,b), and showing that the given finite subcover for [a,s] would also contain all the points of [s, s+δ) from the open cover, therefore including such points in the set S and contradicting the supremum assumption.

My issue arises when I try and make the jump from a closed interval to a closed and bounded set. Part a generalizes very easily, but my method for b doesn't seem to work on discrete sets since there's no guarantee of points being found above the proposed supremum. Could anyone provide a clue or hint for how to proceed without giving it away? I have a feeling it comes from some property of supremums that I'm overlooking, perhaps related to epsilon-neighborhoods, but I've been stuck for a while now and really need help. Thanks!

Comment: I understand the x, but what is s?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $K$ is contained in a bounded interval. Now, consider an open cover of $K$ and add $K^c$ to it.

Comment: Is it possible to explain a bit? How is the complement of the set helping?