# Heine-Borel Theorem using intervals.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

**Problem:** Consider the special case where $K$ is a closed interval. Let $\{O_λ : λ \in Λ\}$ be
an open cover for $[a, b]$ and define $S$ to be the set of all $x ∈ [a, b]$ such that $[a, x]$
has a finite subcover from $\{O_λ : λ \in Λ\}$.

**remark:** The problem asks to show $[a,b]$ has a finite subcover. Which I have done successfully.

**My question:** The problem asks us to use this result to prove the theorem for an arbitrary closed and bounded set.

**My proof?:** Using the hint given in this post of a similar/same question ([Abstracting from a closed interval to a closed and bounded set while proving the Heine-Borel Theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1716284/abstracting-from-a-closed-interval-to-a-closed-and-bounded-set-while-proving-the)) I have this:

Let $K$ be an arbitrary closed and bounded set. Because $K$ is bounded $K \subset [-M,M]$ where M is an upper bound. Let $\{O_λ : λ \in Λ\}$ be an open cover for $K$. Since $K$ is closed $K^c$ must be open, therefore $\{O_λ : λ \in Λ\} \bigcup K^c$ is an open cover for $[-M,M]$. Since  $[-M,M]$ is an interval, there exist a finite subcover of $[-M,M]$  from $\{O_λ : λ \in Λ\} \bigcup K^c$. This implies that $K$ must have a finite subcover as well, otherwise a finite subcover of $[-M,M]$ would not exits.

**I am not sure this proof is right** something feels wrong about it, but I can't figure out exactly what it is.

Any help or maybe hint to finally solve the problem would be appreciated. Thank you !!

Comment: The proof is circular. To prove the theorem is true for closed, bounded $K$, you assumed the theorem is true for a different closed, bounded $[-M, M]$. Instead, make use of the set $S$.

Comment: I proved it for a special type of closed and bounded sets,  the point is to generalize it.

Comment: If you have shown it for any $[-M, M]$, then this is correct.